# Java/Android add 2 bytes (how to tell compiler it won't exceed 127?)

Tags: java, android, byte

one has a value of either 0 or 2 and needs to be added to the other one.

This is what my method call looks so far

`setNumber(new byte[]{(byte) 0xB0, (byte) 52});`

Depending on another parameter I want to do something like

`setNumber(new byte[]{(byte) 0xB0+parameter, (byte) 52});`

So that the `paramater` is something in between 0 and 2. I want to do this because I want to avoid putting if statements at every line where I do this. Also, I think it's the best way performance-wise.

However, Java doesn't let me add these two bytes - I get `incompatible types Required Byte Found int`. What I am trying to achieve DOES work when I simply add the value of the parameter directly as in

`setNumber(new byte[]{(byte) 0xB0+2, (byte) 52});` because the comiler knows it will still stay in byte-range.

So how can I make clear that `parameter` will never go above the value of 2? This code will definitely run no matter what happens to the program, I just need it to compile somehow - and because adding the value manually works, I hope there is a way to make the compiler know that there won't be any issue here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is casting the result of the addition to byte. If the value exceed 127, the bits will be truncated.

```
setNumber(new byte[]{(byte) (0xB0 + param), (byte) 52});
```

Comment: I was just about to submit my own answer but I will tick yours for the effort, thanks so much, so weird that I messed this up!. Enjoy your day my friend.